# How to combine the multiple part linq into one query?

Tags: c#, linq

Operator should be ‘AND’ and not a ‘OR’.

I am trying to refactor the following code and i understood the following way of writing linq query may not be the correct way. Can somone advice me how to combine the following into one query.

> ```
>         AllCompany.Where(itm => itm != null).Distinct().ToList();
>
>         if (AllCompany.Count > 0)
>         {
>             //COMPANY NAME
>             if (isfldCompanyName)
>             {
>                 AllCompany = AllCompany.Where(company => company["Company Name"].StartsWith(fldCompanyName)).ToList();
>             }
>             //SECTOR
>             if (isfldSector)
>             {
>                 AllCompany = AllCompany.Where(company => fldSector.Intersect(company["Sectors"].Split('|')).Any()).ToList();
>             }
>             //LOCATION
>             if (isfldLocation)
>             {
>                 AllCompany = AllCompany.Where(company => fldLocation.Intersect(company["Location"].Split('|')).Any()).ToList();
>
>             }
>             //CREATED DATE
>             if (isfldcreatedDate)
>             {
>                 AllCompany = AllCompany.Where(company => company.Statistics.Created >= createdDate).ToList();
>             }
>             //LAST UPDATED DATE
>             if (isfldUpdatedDate)
>             {
>                 AllCompany = AllCompany.Where(company => company.Statistics.Updated >= updatedDate).ToList();
>             }
>
>             //Allow Placements
>             if (isfldEmployerLevel)
>             {
>                 fldEmployerLevel = (fldEmployerLevel == "Yes") ? "1" : "";
>
>                 AllCompany = AllCompany.Where(company => company["Allow Placements"].ToString() == fldEmployerLevel).ToList();
>             }
> ```

Comment: Don't add `ToList()` at every line, only at the last one, this way it will be only one large query and only one call to db. You can write it on one line, or as it is, right now.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, unless `AllCompany` is of some magic custom type, the first line gives you nothing.
Also I have a doubt that `Distinct`works the way You want it to. I don't know the type of `AllCompany` but I would guess it gives you only reference distinction.

Either way here'w what I think You want:

```
fldEmployerLevel = (fldEmployerLevel == "Yes") ? "1" : "";

var result = AllCompany.Where(itm => itm != null)
    .Where(company => !isfldCompanyName || company["Company Name"].StartsWith(fldCompanyName))
    .Where(company => !isfldSector|| fldSector.Intersect(company["Sectors"].Split('|')).Any())
    .Where(company => !isfldLocation|| fldLocation.Intersect(company["Location"].Split('|')).Any())
    .Where(company => !isfldcreatedDate|| company.Statistics.Created >= createdDate)
    .Where(company => !isfldUpdatedDate|| company.Statistics.Updated >= updatedDate)
    .Where(company => !isfldEmployerLevel|| company["Allow Placements"].ToString() == fldEmployerLevel)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

**Edit:**

I moved `Distinct` to the end of the query to optimize the processing.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying like this;

```
AllCompany = AllCompany .Where(company => (company => company.Statistics.Created >= createdDate)) && (company.Statistics.Updated >= updatedDate));
```

If every part of query is optional (like created date, last update date..) then you can build linq query string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sneaky trick.  If you define the following extension method in its own static class:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<T> WhereAll(params Expression<Predicate<T> filters)
{
    return filters.Aggregate(dbSet, (acc, element) => acc.Where(element));
}
```

then you can write

```
var result = AllCompany.WhereAll(itm => itm != null,
    company => !isfldCompanyName || company["Company Name"].StartsWith(fldCompanyName),
    company => !isfldSectorn || fldSector.Intersect(company["Sectors"].Split('|')).Any(),
    company => !isfldLocation || fldLocation.Intersect(company["Location"].Split('|')).Any(),
    company => !isfldcreatedDate || company.Statistics.Created >= createdDate,
    company => !isfldUpdatedDate || company.Statistics.Updated >= updatedDate,
    company => !isfldEmployerLevel || company["Allow Placements"].ToString() == fldEmployerLevel)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```